PowerApps Patch function glitch/issue
I have a canvas app that is used on a computer as well as mobile phone, and this issue persists on both in the same fashion. My data comes from a simple SharePoint list.
When I go to edit a record from a gallery, I have a few text inputs and usually the last input is a quantity, but the problem can happen in any of the text boxes depending on which data I input LAST. So I usually input data in one text box, then either tab or click to another text box and input that data. I then have a button input to patch the data back into the Sharepoint record. Here's the glitch:
Scenario 1:
If the cursor ends up in say the quantity input box, I input the number and leave the cursor in that input box and directly click the Patch button, that quantity input will not update in the record, but all of the other data updates correctly.
Scenario 2:
If I enter the quantity and either click out of the input box or click back into a different input box, THEN hit the patch button, the entire function works properly and updates the record correctly.
It's almost as if in Scenario 1 the text box doesn't quite "hold" or recognize data has been entered. Once I click out of it like Scenario 2, then it recognizes that data has been input and everything works great.
It's a very strange glitch to even explain, and I know the code works, but it's a problem that I haven't been able to code around to fix. Anyone else have this happen or know of a trick here?
Thanks!

the saving trigger is to leave the input box with your cursor. When you do not "click out" from the input field, the saving process to the app is not finished.

I see, so is that just a global downside of using the patch function? I have to imagine others have come across this nuance with their own custom forms.

seems global. If it is really annoying, you can edit the text input's 'OnChange' paramter with a function, like: every onchange event (= a new character is added/deleted there) populate a variable with the current input text. And the patch function inserts this variable into the desired database.

I bet that will work out pretty well actually. I'll mark that as a solution, thank you!
